# Carrierwave for image upload with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I am trying to upload image using `carrierwave`. Everything seems to be correct, but I am repeatedly getting an error stating:

```
Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<PortfolioUploader:0x007f35a5cad3c0>  
Did you mean?  to_xml
```

Comment: It would help us to help you, if you posted the actual code that caused the problem. It would also help us if you told us what you tried to debug the problem. This is a good read to help you get started: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CarrierWave with Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage may have some issues.
You could try to change your classic `image_tag`.

Assuming you're using something like this :

```
<%= image_tag(@user.image) %>
```

Change it to something like this, using `.url`

```
<%= image_tag(@user.image.url) %>
```

Comment: Thanks alot the issue was with not adding .url.

Comment: Great that it solved your problem ! Could you tag my answer as accepted if it helped you ? Regards

Comment: Yes, it helped. I wonder why should I do that if ActiveStorage is disabled. I have commented it out in application.rb.

Comment: @Hipjea `.to_s` part is not necessary, you can remove it.